# Grayed form while loading

Tags: c#, forms, c#-4.0

i have written the following code in c#. but it didn't the way i want it...
my current code opens the "LoadingForm", but when it shows on screen i can see it as "gray screen with squares" - instead of the Loading_Gif which i have added to that form, hope you help me (By the way, i tried to run the first part of code throw a Thread, it worked normal but i was unable to close that LoadingForm since i can't close it from a different thread than the one i opened it in, and if i try to open and close it in the same Thread that happens at the same time!)
here is my code,
**Note: when movies.usingApi finishes, my form comes back to work in normal way**

```
private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadingForm l1 = new LoadingForm();//a form that shows loading gif while 
    working in the background
    L1.Show();
    Movies.UsingApi();//calling a function to add all available movies to DB
    L1.Close();
}
```

and here is my code using Threads,

```
private void LoadMTV()
{
    Movies.UsingApi();}
    private void ShowLoading()
    {
           L1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread myThread;
        myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new 
        System.Threading.[enter image description here][1]ThreadStart(LoadMTV));
        System.Threading.Thread myThread1;
        myThread1 = new System.Threading.Thread(new 
        System.Threading.ThreadStart(ShowLoading));
        myThread1.Start();
        myThread.Start(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be doing UI work on anything other than the UI thread. Why are you trying to use threading here?

Comment: it seemed to fix my problem, i thought than i need another two threads one for keeping the loading_form moving and one for adding movies to DB all at the same time, so if it's not using Thread what is the way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> It is unsafe to call a control from a thread other than the one that
>   created the control without using the Invoke method. To make a thread-safe
>   call to a Windows Forms control Query the control's InvokeRequired
>   property.
>
> If InvokeRequired returns true, call Invoke with a delegate that makes
>   the actual call to the control.
>
> If InvokeRequired returns false, call the control directly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls

Comment: is there any simple way rather than threads, since i just got to know them by today

Comment: @AhmadEgbaria I don't understand what are you asking, but anyway, if you want to make any task without blocking the UI, threads is the way to go.

Comment: i want to show custom Loading_Form while working in the background using threads but it didn't work